# Mongoose: Updating some/all fields in a Mongodb collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

A settings form is a good example.

On submit, the appropriate collection needs to be updated; and 1, some, none or all of the fields need to be updated.

Assuming I'm not mistaken, Mongoose:

- Ignores fields that aren't defined in the schema.
- Does some low-level validation on the field based on the schema (i.e. it will reject, (ignore?) a value that isn't of the correct type).

So does that mean that the following is *advisable*?

```
.put(function(req, res, next) {
  if (mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(req.params._id)) {
    Collection.update({_id: req.params._id}, { $set: req.body}, function (err, collection) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      res.send(200, {success: true});
    })
  }else{
    res.send(400, {success: false});
  }
})
```

i.e. passing `req.body` directly into the update?

It certainly works, but I can't help but feel it's little lacking in validation/filtering? Is mongoose doing enough in its schema for this approach to be sufficient? Or should I be iterating over each expected field?

I'm happy to set up some tests but thought I'd check with the community and sanity check my approach - any suggested alternatives gratefully received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it happens this would be terrible practice as `Collection.update` bypasses Mongoose validation, so the two assumptions I was making are false in this case.